# How do i export all modules, functions, etc in node.js from one index file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

The question is how do i replicate es6 import/export but in node.js?
I have many controllers and each has a class. I want to export these classes from one file because it saves a lot of lines.

Example in es6:

```
export { default as UserCtrl } from "./UserController";
export { default as DialogCtrl } from "./DialogController";
export { default as MessageCtrl } from "./MessageController";
export { default as UploadFileCtrl } from "./UploadController";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Node.js >= 13, we can use ES6 import/export mechanism. But in CommonJS and legacy style we can do this:

```
// In your exports.js
module.exports = {
    UserCtrl: require('./User.js'),
    MessageCtrl: require('./Message.js'),
    DialogCtrl: require('./Dialog.js')
}
// Import whereever you want
const { UserCtrl, DialogCtrl, MessageCtrl } = require('./exports.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you want to export (lets say export.js)

```
exports.getLogin = (req, res, next) => {
function here
}
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
function here
}
exports.getAnything = (req, res, next) => {
function here
}
exports.postAnything = (req, res, next) => {
function here
}
```

and in the page you want to import:

```
const constName = require('../PATH/export');

app.get('/PATH', constName.getLogin)
```

So you can use the function by the constName dot the function name you export.
Hope it helped.